# An error occurred building visual studio cordova app using multi-device-hybrid-apps

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, installation, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am getting 3 fatal errors.  I installed the android SDK 19 as well. Any ideas???

```
An error occurred while listing Android targets

C:\Project\AngularJS_ToDo_Sample_for_Multi-Device_Hybrid_Apps\JavaScript\AngularJSTodo\EXEC 1   1 AngularJSToDo

C:\Users\wil\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8

C:\Project\AngularJS_ToDo_Sample_for_Multi-Device_Hybrid_Apps\JavaScript\AngularJSTodo\EXEC 1   1 AngularJSToDo

The command ""C:\Users\wil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName "AngularJSToDo"" exited with code 8.

C:\Users\wil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets  115 5   AngularJSToDo
```

I tried @Freddy's answer, everything looked right but it didn't work. I got this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp2, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(90,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.22 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ojeaygbd.tal\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-mda
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 0.1.1
1>  ------ Current globally installed version : 0.1.1
1>  ------ Build settings:
1>  ------    buildCommand: prepare
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: BlankCordovaApp2
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Project\vsPhoneGap\BlankCordovaApp2
1>  ------ Creating app at C:\Project\vsPhoneGap\BlankCordovaApp2\bld\Debug
1>  Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloCordova" and id "io.cordova.hellocordova" at location "C:\Project\vsPhoneGap\BlankCordovaApp2\bld\Debug"
1>  Using stock cordova hello-world application.
1>  cordova library for "www" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
1>  Copying stock Cordova www assets into "C:\Project\vsPhoneGap\BlankCordovaApp2\bld\Debug\www"
1>  ------ Copying app files to www
1>  ------ Done copying app files to www
1>  ------ Copying res files
1>  ------ Creating directory: res
1>  ------ Done copying res files
1>  ------ Adding platform: android
1>  cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
1>  Checking if platform "android" passes minimum requirements...
1>  Creating android project...
1>  Running command: C:\Users\wil\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat --cli C:\Project\vsPhoneGap\BlankCordovaApp2\bld\Debug\platforms\android io.cordova.BlankCordovaApp2 BlankCordovaApp2
1>  
1>  C:\Users\wil\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;
1>                            ^
1>EXEC : error : An error occurred while listing Android targets
1>      at C:\Users\wil\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:87:29
1>      at _rejected (C:\Users\wil\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
1>      at C:\Users\wil\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:834:30
1>      at Promise.when (C:\Users\wil\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
1>      at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\wil\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
1>      at C:\Users\wil\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
1>      at flush (C:\Users\wil\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
1>      at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
1>  Command finished with error code 8: C:\Users\wil\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat --cli,C:\Project\vsPhoneGap\BlankCordovaApp2\bld\Debug\platforms\android,io.cordova.BlankCordovaApp2,BlankCordovaApp2
1>  
1>  C:\Users\wil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;
1>                            ^
1>EXEC : error : C:\Users\wil\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
1>      at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\wil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:126:23)
1>      at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
1>      at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
1>      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
1>C:\Users\wil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(115,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Users\wil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName "BlankCordovaApp2"" exited with code 8.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========



00:03.210 - Failed  - Debug Android - BlankCordovaApp2.jsproj

Total build time: 00:00.000

========== : 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped, Completed at 5/17/2014 12:01:25 AM ==========
```

Comment: Thanks to Freddy I got it to build now and looks like it's working but I do have this error.                                                  5/21/2014 12:28:40 AM: An exception was thrown when running bundles: System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was getting the same errors.  There are three environment variables that must be defined:

1) %JAVA_HOME% -- C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55

2) %ADT_HOME% -- C:\Users\YOUR_NAME_GOES_HERE\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

3) %ANT_HOME%  -- C:\apache-ant-1.9.3

**NOTE -- The paths for these programs may be totally different on your PC - You have to figure out the install paths for each.**

Once you have defined these variables then copy the entry below into the Path variable for your user account (I have read elsewhere that it is best to add these to the beginning of the entry and not the end - thats what I did and it worked for me).  Reboot PC after making all changes.

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ADT_HOME%\tools;%ADT_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin;
```

*Taken from the "Installing 3rd party software manually" section in the official documentation.

Comment: what do you know, it worked after restarting few times.  Thanks!

Comment: updated answer to reflect that a reboot may be needed.  Glad to hear you're up and running - happy coding!

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, no reboot required! Thank-you!

Comment: The path values listed above also have to go into the system PATH not just the user PATH

Answer (score 2):

i had same problem, after installing Android SDK Build-tool from Android SDK Manager
the problem was solved

1. go to directory of Android SDK
   as ...\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
2. open SDK Manager.exe
3. in list of packages 
   Android SDK Build tools package not install
   and sdk manager will auto select lastest Rev. for you to install it
4. click Install Packages
   wait until it done
5. try to build project again

and i got apk files at directory
.........\bin\Android\Debug
and i can run it in BlueStacks

sorry my english language is bad . -*-

Comment: i answer the question by install SDK Build tool 
to fix problem
sry if my language skill make you confuse

Comment: Sorry, my skill arent the best either. :)

Comment: Thanks guys for helping out but nothing seems to work.  I have same errors.  this is annoying

Answer (score 1):

GO to Command Prompt and type:

```
npm install -g glob
```

Now try running your app, It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to following these steps in order:

- Ensure that the Android SDK is installed at %localappdata%/Android/android-sdk
- Ensure that Android is updated to the latest API (API 19 at the time of writing)
- Ensure the Android SDK path is setup correctly:

  - Add ADT_HOME as an environment variable and point it to the android-sdk folder
  - Add to System Path: "%ADT_HOME%\tools;%ADT_HOME%\platform-tools"
- Reboot your machine

This should resolve the issue.

*Taken from the "Installing 3rd party software manually" section in the official [documentation](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397716).