# Build Error when Compiling Cordova Project in Visual Studio 2013 (Update 2)

Tags: cordova, npm, visual-studio-cordova

I am having the following error whenever I try to build a Cordova Project in Visual Studio 2013 (Update 2).

> Error 11  Cannot find module 'config-chain'
>
> Error 12  The command
>   ""C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli"
>   prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir .
>   --projectName "BlankCordovaApp2"" exited with code 8.

I followed the instructions from msdn to install the required files.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a duplicate question. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668519/an-error-occurred-building-visual-studio-cordova-app-using-multi-device-hybrid-a/23704446

Answer (score 0):

I think your installation of npm is broken, because config-chain is a npm core module.
Try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

From Visual studio:  TOOLS->Options-> Tools For Apache Cordova -> Clear Cordova Cache