# Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio: ripple emulator doesn't start after the build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ripple, visual-studio-cordova

I try to build a empty project with target platform Ripple (Galaxy)/Android and 
but when finish the build Visual Studio open Chrome with address

```
http://localhost:4400/___vs_to_ripple___/index.html?_enableripple=cordova-3.0.0-NexusGalaxy
```

without run the ripple emulator, of course I get an error. Do I must set some environment variable?

Thanks in advance

below my output window

```
    1>------ Inizio compilazione: Progetto: BlankCordovaApp1, Configurazione: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(90,5): warning : Al compilatore TypeScript Compiler non è stato fornito alcun file per la compilazione. La compilazione verrà ignorata.
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.11.13 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\c5uzit0w.pdv\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-mda
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 0.1.1
1>  ------ Current globally installed version : 0.1.1
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Build settings:
1>  ------    buildCommand: prepare
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: BlankCordovaApp1
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\aaaaaaa\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1
1>  ------ App dir c:\aaaaaaa\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Debug already exists
1>  ------ Copying app files to www
1>  ------ Done copying app files to www
1>  ------ Copying res files
1>  ------ Done copying res files
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Certificate copy from c:\aaaaaaa\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\res\cert\android to platforms\android
1>  ------ Done copying certificate files to platforms\android
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: 
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins: 
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins: 
1>  ------ Preparing platform: android
1>  cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
1>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
1>  Wrote out Android application name to "BlankCordovaApp1"
1>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.BlankCordovaApp1"
2>------ Inizio distribuzione: Progetto: BlankCordovaApp1, Configurazione: Debug Android ------
========== Compilazione: 1 completate, 0 non riuscite, 0 aggiornate, 0 ignorate ==========
========== Distribuzione: 1 completate, 0 non riuscite, 0 ignorate ==========
```

Comment: .@Fabio - could you check your system configuration as explained at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23704446/1277291

Comment: I checked the my environment variables as reported from the documentation and are ok , in fact the build phase ends successfully but after chrome  starts with an url wrong and without run ripple. Thanks

Comment: Could you add the output from your VS output window?

Comment: I think that the problem is in the white space contains in my username  (C:\Users\name surname\...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved!
The problem was a white space contained in my profile folder. I renamed my profile folder and now works perfectly!