# Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio: ripple emulator doesn't start

Tags: path, ripple, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have the same problem like Fabio in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934843/multi-device-hybrid-apps-for-visual-studio-ripple-emulator-doesnt-start-after). Unfortunately I can't add answer. I know that problem can be connected with white space in my user name. Can I change path from "c:\users\forename surname...", to  "c:\users\forenamesurname..." ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change your username, I suggest creating a new user with the desired name. As far as dependencies are concerned, in case you used the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps installer for all your dependencies, here are the changes to be made:

- Create a new user and login
- Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features
- Uninstall Android SDK
- Download the Android SDK again from here.
- Install it choosing "Install for all users on this machine"
- Install the following packages in the Android SDK manager:

[image]

- Open your system Environment Settings:
- Change the ADT_HOME to: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"  (or if you chose a custom install directory)

Everything should run as expected now.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, renaming your profile folder should work. Be sure to update any environment variables and paths accordingly.

Comment: I fear that changes can damage something in my other installed applications. So, if I change environment variables with paths it should work properly ? Thanks

Comment: Creating a new username and profile is indeed safer as it will not impact any other installed applications.