# Debugger error "Unable to attach. Invalid Pointer" from Ripple

Tags: visual-studio-2013, emulation, ripple, visual-studio-cordova

I've just installed the [Multi-device Hybrid Apps preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722381.aspx) for Visual Studio 2013, and I'm getting an error when attempting to debug via Ripple for iOS or Android.

"Unable to attach. Invalid Pointer"

There is no useful output provided by Visual Studio 2013, rather the debugger just doesn't attach to the browser Ripple emulator after showing the exception. The exception happens immediately and the debugger never attaches. I've had this error occur since installation, so it shouldn't have anything to do with the project itself. I checked my paths and they appear to be correct.

System Properties -> Advanced -> System Variables:

- ADT_HOME  | C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
- ANT_HOME  | C:\apache-ant-1.9.3
- JAVA_HOME | C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55

Global Path Variable (last section):

- C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows
  Performance
  Toolkit\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ADT_HOME%\tools;%ADT_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin;C:\Program
  Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\

I've made sure that the latest android SDK was installed via the package manager, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668519/an-error-occurred-building-visual-studio-cordova-app-using-multi-device-hybrid-a#23708069). I've also done multiple reboots since the installation.

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

**Edit**
Here's a screen showing Visual Studio's lack of output. There's some general output written while building, but the output is erased immediately when the exception occurs.

[image: Visual Studio Output]

I also noticed that I cannot run my application in the Android emulator, which shows that there may be a general installation problem. When trying to run the Android Emulator in Debug mode, I get the following errors:

[image: Android emulator problems]

Comment: Could you update the question with a output stack from Visual Studio?

Comment: For the Android emulator, it seems like you haven't created any images. Start the AVD Manager (type "android avd" in your command prompt) and create one. Once that's done, try running it again for the Android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer this question in 2 parts:

### Debugger not attaching

Multi Device Hybrid Apps CTP1/1.1 only supports debugging on Android devices and emulators 4.4+. This is probably why your debugger fails to attach.

### Android emulator not found

It seems that you have not created an AVD (android virtual device), which is why F5 to the Android emulator fails.

Open command prompt and type

```
android avd
```

Now, create an AVD image with your preferred configuration and then try to F5 again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Don't know if it helps, but in my case I had to uninstall Resharper (Version 8.2).