# Error installing npm package

Tags: cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am quite new with the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps and Cordova programming.
So I decided  I would download a Sample from VS website
I downloaded all the three (WinJS, AngularJS , BackboneJS ), but none of them work when I try to build them.

Here is the error I get:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: AngularJSToDo, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
 1>C:\Users\■■■■■\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(158,5): error : Error installing local npm package.

 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

 ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

[image: pIC]
I Installed all the components in Multi-Device Hybrid Apps Installation and don't know what am I missing.

I would like to request your help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the MDA targets did not get installed properly.  You can uninstall them and create a new project which should trigger a reinstall, or if that still doesn't work you can install them manually by following the instructions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477665/cannot-create-new-project-vs2013-and-multi-hybrid-device-app/25514980#25514980).

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But now I get another error: "C:\Users\■■■■■\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8", please help. Notice, I added all the PATH variables needed (Android sdk, JAVA, ANT)

Comment: Verify that you have followed the instructions in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464326/cannot-run-cordova-applications-using-visual-studio-2013).  Be sure to add the required environment variables to your system path as well and reboot your machine after doing so.

Comment: hi @Ellen.... I did that above process.. But still got the same error.. Could you help me?