# Debugger error “Unable to attach. The System cannot find the file specified” from Ripple and Android emulator

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, android-emulator, ripple, visual-studio-cordova

Debugger error “Unable to attach. The System cannot find the file specified” from the Ripple and Android emulator

I've just installed the Multi-device Hybrid Apps preview for Visual Studio 2013, and I'm getting an error when attempting to debug against Ripple or other emulators

The build process is always completed successfully, but while start debugging the VS show up this error message:

“Unable to attach. The System cannot find the file specified”

[image: VS2013 Multi-device Hybrid Apps Debugging error]

There is no useful output provided by Visual Studio 2013, rather the debugger just doesn't attach to the browser Ripple emulator after showing the exception. 
The exception happens immediately and the debugger never attaches. 
I've had this error occur since installation, so it shouldn't have anything to do with the project itself. 
I checked my paths and they appear to be correct as in [@Freddy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23704446/2467917), because the build is always successful.

Comment: Does the app launch to Ripple/emulator though?

Comment: Yes of course, the app launched on both ripple and android emulator correctly, but the VS showed up the same message and the debugging process ended.

Comment: Is Visual Studio installed on non-system drive? We have seen this issue when VS was installed on non-system drive.

Comment: yes, I was installed on D drive

Comment: I have tried the work around of @Ellen answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25900002/2467917), then everything is fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may happen when Visual Studio is installed on a non-system drive.  If that's the case, you can work around it by copying the assembly typescriptSourceMapReader.dll from

```
<SystemDrive>\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
```

to the same location on the drive where Visual Studio is installed.
Relaunching VS after doing this should fix the issue.

Comment: "Program Files(x86)" is missing a space and should be "Program Files (x86)"

Comment: @Zakaria  i have only C drive in my system and i have installed VS2015 with Apache Cordova. The Ripple emulator always gives the above mentioned Error.

Comment: I installed VS 2015 on win server 2012,first I faced some issues (ScriptedSandbox64.exe ) 
I show  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31973059/2467917, then I upgrade to 2012 R2, repair VS installation,update some security options in IE, then follow steps urls:
http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/
http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/
http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#vstac
check dependency  : VS IDE >> tools >> options >> tools for apache cordova >> cordova tools >> run dependency checker