# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova Tools - When Launching Ripple An error "scriptedsandbox64.exe has stopped working" Appears

Tags: cordova, debugging, ripple, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I launch the ripple debugger, the process scriptedsandbox64.exe stops working and both the DOM explorer and the debugging tools show a huge refresh button, clicking on said button only results in the error appearing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Internet Explorer version was 10, the cordova tools need version 11 to work properly, upgrading to v11 solves the issue.

Comment: I have IE 11 (11.0.27) and I am facing the same issue. Any idea why it is occuring?

Comment: Installing IE 11 worked for me, if it's not working for you [try this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071997/scriptedsandbox64-exe-has-stopped-working-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and it works when installing IE11