# ScriptedSandbox64.exe has stopped working - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, sandbox, diagnostic-tools

This is the second time I've seen the error "Scripted Sandbox64.exe has stopped working" in Visual Studio 2015.

In my particular case, I was building a Windows Forms application and you place the application into the system tray in Windows.  This application also writes files using System.IO.  The project has nothing more than that.  Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition crashes.

[image]

Comment: http://systemexplorer.net/file-database/file/scriptedsandbox64-exe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scriptedsandbox64.exe crashes in visual studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238845/scriptedsandbox64-exe-crashes-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Installing IE 11 didn't work, when I tested it last year.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I'm facing exactly the same now with VS 2015 Update 3 , IE 11 and  disabled "Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging"

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Disable the Diagnostic tool under

> Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging

More information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31904957/2856307

Comment: I had this issue appear while already having this checked (since a long time ago).

Answer (score 8):

Just adding the information that @Bahien Nguyen provided in his answer.

Reference:

http://www.expertdebugger.com/2016/01/19/how-to-fix-visual-studio-2015-error-faulting-application-name-scriptedsandbox64-exe-has-stopped-working/

## How to fix Visual Studio 2015 error Faulting application name ScriptedSandbox64.exe has stopped working

I am trying to debug a windows application in Visual Studio 2015. I have already installed the latest updates. After the debugging starts, I get the following pop up error ScriptedSandbox64.exe has stopped working A problem caused program to stop working correctly.

[image]

The event viewer is showing the following details

Faulting application name: ScriptedSandbox64.exe, version: 14.0.24720.0, time stamp: 0x564e98d0

Faulting module name: ScriptedSandbox64.exe, version: 14.0.24720.0, time stamp: 0x564e98d0

Exception code: 0xc0000602

Fault offset: 0x000000000000f933

Faulting process id: 0x51c

Faulting application start time: 0x01d152888b333a1c

Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ScriptedSandbox64.exe

Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ScriptedSandbox64.exe

Report Id: 029bb0e0-771e-4046-bbc1-2c69686f144a

Faulting package full name:

Faulting package-relative application ID:

IDE gets locked up due to this and the only option is to click on close program.

Solution

This process is launched during debugging. Stop Visual Studio debugging session.

Disable the Diagnostic tool under Tools->Options->Debugging->General disable the option Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging

[image]

Debugger still works after unchecking the above option.ScriptedSandbox64.exe no more throws any errors.

Dear Reader,

Please share your feedback about this article . This will enable me to improve this for the benefit of other readers.

Comment: Doesn't work at all; still have this issue even after VS2015 Update 3

Answer (score 2):

Solution for now is to install Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition and retrofit the project by changing the *.csproj file XML.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who has this problem:
I experienced the same problem debugging a WPF application today in VS2015 Community Update 2. I am sure that I did not have this before but I dont know how it crept back in. As mentioned before, disabling the Diagnostic Tools solves the problem. Unfortunately, this is not an option for me. Luckily, installing the "Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 (KB3151378)" solved the problem for good. Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt695655.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, same dialog as OP posted, but then I encountered the same when running the application in debug mode. That helped me find what was causing this error in my application.

I traced it down to an iteration through `DataGridViewRows`, which would contain about 1800+ rows. My iteration was to set a checkbox value to true, but I ended up not needing to do that anyways. Once I removed this, the application would run okay.