# ScriptedSandbox64.exe has stopped working when opening word add-in dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, office-js, office-addins

I'm currently making a Word Web Add-in using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition (developing on Windows Server 2016 Standard - with RDP).

I need to add a dialog window to my application, because I need a little more screen estate for a part of my application.

So I'm showing a dialog as it's been explained over here:
https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/TestDialog.html');
```

TestDialog.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Test Dialog</title>
    <script src="https://www.promisejs.org/polyfills/promise-7.0.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    Test dialog
</body>
</html>
```

The dialog pops up succesfully, but right after that I get a windows error "ScriptedSandbox64.exe has stopped working". Also, after that, when I execute any code to sync the document, I get the error:

> GeneralException: An internal error occured

I suppose this is caused by the crashed ScriptedSandbox.exe.
When I do a `console.log()` of the exception, and I try to look at the exception information in VisualStudio, I also get the ScriptedSandbox.exe error.

I tried the solution from this stackoverflow issue, but this does help in my case:
[ScriptedSandbox64.exe has stopped working - Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071997/scriptedsandbox64-exe-has-stopped-working-visual-studio-2015)

In the windows event log, I see the following:

- When I get the error in Office:

> Fault bucket , type 0 Event Name: VisualStudioNonFatalErrors2
>   Response: Not available Cab Id: 0 Problem signature: P1:
>   ScriptedSandbox64.exe P2: 15.0.26228.9 D15RTWSVC P3:
>   VS/ScriptedHost/Dom Version:1.0 P4: Title:Dom Version:1.0 Domain:
>   microsoft.com P5: 15.0.26228.0 P6: 58b562f7 P7: res://c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\webclient\diagnostics\toolwindows\vsresources.dll/#23/console/ConsoleMerged.js
>   P8: 5938 P9: **Target already added: uid0** P10: ScriptedPluginHost
>   Attached files: \?\C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\SPE9F38.tmp
>   These files may be available here: Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for
>   solution: 0 Report Id: 66676cbf-1228-11e7-85c1-d8d385e237a2 Report
>   Status: 262144 Hashed bucket:

- When I get the error in Visual Studio, upon trying to get the exception information:

> Fault bucket 127830074891, type 5 Event Name:
>   VisualStudioNonFatalErrors2 Response: Not available Cab Id: 0 Problem
>   signature: P1: ScriptedSandbox64.exe P2: 15.0.26228.9 D15RTWSVC P3:
>   VS/ScriptedHost/Dom Version:1.0 P4: Title:Dom Version:1.0
>   Domain:microsoft.com P5: 15.0.26228.0 P6: 58b562f7 P7:
>   res://c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\webclient\diagnostics\toolwindows\vsresources.dll/#23/console/ConsoleMerged.js
>   P8: 3632 P9: **Unable to get property 'channel' of undefined or null
>   reference** P10: ScriptedPluginHost Attached files:
>   \?\C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\SPE862B.tmp
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER86C1.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
>   These files may be available here:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Critical_ScriptedSandbox6_f7aa31cc56162be295698083cac29769faeb4a7_00000000_17ac8f0e
>   Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id:
>   b0b5bb75-1228-11e7-85c1-d8d385e237a2 Report Status: 1 Hashed bucket:
>   558ba9ae3c60bfdc002e0f1b9732736d

Does anyone have any idea of what the issue might be, or how I could work around it?

Comment: I think these might be 2 seperate issues, one being the error, and the other one that you are unable to sync the document from within an add-in dialog.
Does anyone know if it's normal that you cannot sync from within a dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, these are indeed 2 seperate issues.

It seems that it's impossible to sync to the document from within an add-in dialog. To fix this, I'm now passing the information back to the main user interface using this code:

```
    Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify({
        type: 'myCustomType',
        data: myData
    }))
```

The other problem, the message "ScriptedSandbox64.exe has stopped working", it only appears when you're using Visual Studio, not in the published version. I just click it away now.

Comment: Is anyone from Microsoft following this conversation? The "ScriptedSandbox64.exe" error is very annoying. I get it even when creating a blank Word Add-In using the Visual Studio 2017 template.